# ApiController Routing Isn't Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

Below I'm going to insert the code for the following:

- Global.asax
- DatabasesController (**ApiController**)
- The error I receive when trying to navigate to the default api route.

It is my understand that what I'm doing here is 100% correct, and in fact I've verified that the code lines up with an example I found from [Mike Wasson](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). **Hopefully you can show me the way to getting this working!**

*Thanks all!*

### Global.asax

Below is the code that exists in the Global.asax and this method is called by `Application_Start()` which was generated by the template.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

### DatabasesController.cs

This is the `ApiController`, and it inherits from `ApiController` and was created by the template in Visual Studio.  The `databases` field is declared as `Database[]` in the class.

```
public IEnumerable<Database> GetAllDatabases()
{
    return databases;
}

public Database GetDatabaseById(string id)
{
    return databases.Where(d => d.Name == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

### Error

This is the error I'm receiving when I try to access it with what should be the default api path (as far as I understand it anyway...HA).

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddWithoutValidation(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddWithoutValidation(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddWithoutValidation(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)'.]
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.AddHeaderToHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, String headerName, String[] headerValues) +0
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ConvertRequest(HttpContextBase httpContextBase) +248
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +79
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +268
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: @JP. I just modified it, sorry.

Comment: As a matter of interest are you using the beta or RC? Have you upgraded versions recently?

Comment: Might want to take a look at the following 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862728/asp-net-web-api-error-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2012-rc-method-not-found

Comment: @JP. (Beta) v4.0.20126.16343 - but NuGet says there is no update.

Comment: @JP. Post the fact that I needed to upgrade my version as the answer and I'll accept it. NuGet Package Manager is not my friend, it said there were no updates, and then I went back and checked again and then there were. It's working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to upgrade your version of webapi from beta to RC!