# customize data annotation in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

right now I am doing WebAPI and as we know each controller will have its own url. Do have option to change those url what ever we like. Per example below urls are current Web API.

```
Do we really want to use mixed case in urls?
            - http://localhost:8282/api/encode/
            - http://localhost:8282/api/techdisciplines/
            - http://localhost:8282/api/memstatus/
            - http://localhost:8282/api/isstaff/
```

Want to change them to below url with changing major code effect. Just changing data annotation.

```
         - http://localhost:8282/api/cus/encode/<customer id>
        - http://localhost:8282/api/cus/disciplines/<token>
        - http://localhost:8282/api/cus/mem_status/<token>
        - http://localhost:8282/api/cus/is_staff/<token>
```

Like Java has which automatically find the method.

```
    @Path("customer/{i_Constit}/subscriptions")
    public Response getSubscriptions(@PathParam("i_Constit") String customerId)
    {
                          ....
                          ...
```

Comment: You can use Attribute Routing in Web API 2: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Attribute Routing in Web API 2: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Okay one issue I had run into was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862728/asp-net-web-api-error-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2012-rc-method-not-found So basically I just removed old Nuget Packages and got new ones and targeted 4.5 My Web API was simple enough so I could do that way.